# Magento 2 - Display Phone Number Block Error

Tags: magento, magento2

I'm trying to use a block to display the store phone number and getting this error:

> Recoverable Error: Argument 1 passed to Magento\Store\Model\Information::getStoreInformationObject() must be an instance of Magento\Store\Model\Store, none given

Here's my code:

```
<?php

namespace MyVendor\Custom\Block;

use Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template;

class Phone extends Template
{
    protected $_storeInfo;

    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template\Context $context,
        \Magento\Store\Model\Information $storeInfo,
        array $data = []
    ) {
        parent::__construct($context, $data);
        $this->_storeInfo = $storeInfo;
    }

    public function getPhoneNumber()
    {
        return $this->_storeInfo->getStoreInformationObject()->getPhone();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

hollaholla bruva

I had the same problem and found the solution [Here](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/149009/magento-2-fatal-error-uncaught-error-call-to-a-member-function-dispatch)

From what it looks like, you have to set a store object as an argument for the getStoreInformationObject function. You can do this by injecting the

```
\Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface
```

model into your constructor.

Next create a variable for this

```
$this->_storeManagerInterface = $storeManagerInterface;
```

And pass the `getStore()` function as an argument to your `getStoreInformationObject()` function.

```
$this->_storeInfo->getStoreInformationObject($this->_storeManagerInterface->getStore())->getPhone();
```

Your final code should look something like this:

```
    class Helloworld extends \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template{
         protected $_storeInfo;
         protected $_storeManagerInterface;

         public function __construct(
              \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template\Context $context,
              \Magento\Store\Model\Information $storeInfo,
              \Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface $storeManagerInterface,
              array $data = []
         )
         {
              parent::__construct($context, $data);
              $this->_storeInfo = $storeInfo;
              $this->_storeManagerInterface = $storeManagerInterface;
         }
         public function getPhoneNumber()
         {
              $telephone = $this->_storeInfo->getStoreInformationObject($this->_storeManagerInterface->getStore())->getPhone();
              return (!empty($telephone)) ? $telephone : '' ;
         }
    }
```

I also added some validation to ensure the value isn't empty as this will throw an error.

Hope I helped with this,
Good luck